# table show/hide remember the selection

Tags: php, cookies, jscript

I am a beginner and used jscript in my php page to hide/show table using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setTable(what){
if(document.getElementById(what).style.display=="none"){
document.getElementById(what).style.display="block";
}
else if(document.getElementById(what).style.display=="block"){
document.getElementById(what).style.display="none";
}
}
</script>
```

and display/hide table2 using:

```
<a href="#" onclick= "setTable('table2')"><img src="/icons/index.png" width="55" height="55"></a>
```

My problem is that while using this code, in case of any browser activity, the table is reset back to default state. I am struggling to enable users once they show/hide table it should continue even when refresh/or navigate happens within the pages. I know I should use cookies but have no idea. Please someone guide me.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cookies to store table state.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var tableState = getCookie("table2state");
if (tableState != "") {
    document.getElementById('table2').style.display = tableState;
}

function setTable(what) {
    if (document.getElementById(what).style.display == "none") {
        document.getElementById(what).style.display = "block";
        setCookie(what + 'state', "block", 365);
    } else if (document.getElementById(what).style.display == "block") {
        document.getElementById(what).style.display = "none";
        setCookie(what + 'state', "none", 365);
    }
}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried but not working. should I change anything at <href...onlcik event?

Comment: @user3792463 please make sure your javascript block is at end of your html file and not at start.